# large PHP _POST not working when I use Apache vhost Proxy

Tags: php, routes, timeout, apache2, vhosts

I have this set up on a"gateway" Apache server. it then forwards to a second server (I do not want exposed.)

the main "www" server simply hosts a website and forwards subdomains

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.firewall.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName behind.firewall.co.uk
  ServerAdmin root@localhost
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.53/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.53/
  SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1
  <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/behind.firewall.co.uk.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/behind.firewall.err.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

the problem is that if the _POST is very large (and by "very large" I mean about 20 drop downs in a form that is _POSTed) the gateway Apache server simply locks. It refuses to forward it properly (at all) and it will (in the end) time out for 60s before even doing anything. It doesn't refuse to forward it, it does nothing for 60s.

but if I swap the gateway servers around it works fine, i.e. a large post to `behind.firewall.co.uk` direct.

does anyone know what I am doing wrong, what setting I am missing to ensure _POSTs work? (note: smaller posts DO work, so I am assuming it's a setting somewhere, but these are only forms of 20 drop downs hardly cumbersome)